# Instagram Feed Slick Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, instagram, slick.js

I'm trying to create a carousel slider with instagram feed using jquery.instagramFeed.js with slick.js.

On codepen I inserted the instagram feed and the slick slider below to see if the slick is working.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/adrianovarlotta/pen/XWKNBqg

I changed some codes on instagram feed js, adding on line 132:

`html += "<section class='regular slider instagram_gallery'>";`

and closing that section on line 173:

`html += "</section>";`

Trying to make work the slick slider on instagram feed without sucess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using the `instagramFeed.js` callback option to run a function which returns the instagram user data object which you can use to build a slick slider.

The returned instagramFeed data object is pretty heavy but see my demo below, which uses the returned data object and loops through all the users media items, builds a custom `slides` object and stops at the media count value, here is the custom object we've made...

The max slides you can ever get for a user is 12, and for tags is 72.

```
{
  B27UTWZDlZY: {
    150: "https://scontent-lht6-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/e35/c157.0.406.406a/s150x150/69856901_215241699458552_7535240597822423815_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-lht6-1.cdninstagram.com&amp;_nc_cat=108&amp;_nc_ohc=DWSHUK-9GosAX9mw4Ol&amp;tp=16&amp;oh=4547a183de107937cd4fc8829cb28ff6&amp;oe=5F96F63E",
    240: "https://scontent-lht6-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/e35/c157.0.406.406a/s240x240/69856901_215241699458552_7535240597822423815_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-lht6-1.cdninstagram.com&amp;_nc_cat=108&amp;_nc_ohc=DWSHUK-9GosAX9mw4Ol&amp;tp=16&amp;oh=307c0ce577bbeea2fb9ee4bbb898097a&amp;oe=5F96C138",
    320: "https://scontent-lht6-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/e35/c157.0.406.406a/s320x320/69856901_215241699458552_7535240597822423815_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-lht6-1.cdninstagram.com&amp;_nc_cat=108&amp;_nc_ohc=DWSHUK-9GosAX9mw4Ol&amp;tp=16&amp;oh=9f90ae2b01ff38419e23ee07ef3c2a02&amp;oe=5F96874E",
    480: "https://scontent-lht6-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/e35/c157.0.406.406a/69856901_215241699458552_7535240597822423815_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-lht6-1.cdninstagram.com&amp;_nc_cat=108&amp;_nc_ohc=DWSHUK-9GosAX9mw4Ol&amp;oh=33ec0085b8863af3ffda4bd1a59c809e&amp;oe=5F970099",
    640: "https://scontent-lht6-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/e35/c157.0.406.406a/69856901_215241699458552_7535240597822423815_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-lht6-1.cdninstagram.com&amp;_nc_cat=108&amp;_nc_ohc=DWSHUK-9GosAX9mw4Ol&amp;oh=33ec0085b8863af3ffda4bd1a59c809e&amp;oe=5F970099"
  },
  BvzWaX8hg50: {
    150: "https://scontent-lhr8-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/e35/s150x150/54511581_155220282170447_1722264597870720283_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-lhr8-1.cdninstagram.com&amp;_nc_cat=111&amp;_nc_ohc=YdpTrs4jVysAX-88LWe&amp;_nc_tp=15&amp;oh=976a0dd9be4381a97f256953d10ed769&amp;oe=5FBFD370",
    240: "https://scontent-lhr8-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/e35/s240x240/54511581_155220282170447_1722264597870720283_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-lhr8-1.cdninstagram.com&amp;_nc_cat=111&amp;_nc_ohc=YdpTrs4jVysAX-88LWe&amp;_nc_tp=15&amp;oh=2bc255b974c57f4c2ab81a7fcc726e1c&amp;oe=5FBE4926",
    320: "https://scontent-lhr8-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/e35/s320x320/54511581_155220282170447_1722264597870720283_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-lhr8-1.cdninstagram.com&amp;_nc_cat=111&amp;_nc_ohc=YdpTrs4jVysAX-88LWe&amp;_nc_tp=15&amp;oh=d3da5b238d4a70ec2f9fe7cf09ea144e&amp;oe=5FBFD2A0",
    480: "https://scontent-lhr8-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/e35/s480x480/54511581_155220282170447_1722264597870720283_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-lhr8-1.cdninstagram.com&amp;_nc_cat=111&amp;_nc_ohc=YdpTrs4jVysAX-88LWe&amp;_nc_tp=15&amp;oh=250ecd60fa86c6aeabd2a236036d1f7b&amp;oe=5FBC2546",
    640: "https://scontent-lhr8-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/sh0.08/e35/s640x640/54511581_155220282170447_1722264597870720283_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-lhr8-1.cdninstagram.com&amp;_nc_cat=111&amp;_nc_ohc=YdpTrs4jVysAX-88LWe&amp;_nc_tp=24&amp;oh=84e330986ce3ae71ed1895c5a2a9690b&amp;oe=5FBDF4C9"
  },
  ByahrrSDqVa: {
    150: "https://scontent-lhr8-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/e35/s150x150/63430826_120138045872791_614866485576038131_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-lhr8-1.cdninstagram.com&amp;_nc_cat=107&amp;_nc_ohc=lIqX8s7NhLQAX-LlxUs&amp;_nc_tp=15&amp;oh=123a990bf0f44e97caacc68994832055&amp;oe=5FBE7B20",
    240: "https://scontent-lhr8-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/e35/s240x240/63430826_120138045872791_614866485576038131_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-lhr8-1.cdninstagram.com&amp;_nc_cat=107&amp;_nc_ohc=lIqX8s7NhLQAX-LlxUs&amp;_nc_tp=15&amp;oh=712e92714159df1a7deedb3e8f9fdc23&amp;oe=5FBD1AAB",
    320: "https://scontent-lhr8-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/e35/s320x320/63430826_120138045872791_614866485576038131_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-lhr8-1.cdninstagram.com&amp;_nc_cat=107&amp;_nc_ohc=lIqX8s7NhLQAX-LlxUs&amp;_nc_tp=15&amp;oh=ce04f8a32e2fe225e66b7cb4f99c5987&amp;oe=5FBC3C13",
    480: "https://scontent-lhr8-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/e35/s480x480/63430826_120138045872791_614866485576038131_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-lhr8-1.cdninstagram.com&amp;_nc_cat=107&amp;_nc_ohc=lIqX8s7NhLQAX-LlxUs&amp;_nc_tp=15&amp;oh=5a4c624b33388220fc0623204f0d006d&amp;oe=5FBF8D4F",
    640: "https://scontent-lhr8-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/sh0.08/e35/s640x640/63430826_120138045872791_614866485576038131_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-lhr8-1.cdninstagram.com&amp;_nc_cat=107&amp;_nc_ohc=lIqX8s7NhLQAX-LlxUs&amp;_nc_tp=24&amp;oh=c9ba3bee3d16a32ceeaee5f951cdc592&amp;oe=5FBC907F"
  },
  ...
}
```

Now we have created our latest media object, we can then builds a slick slider using this custom data `slides` object variable.

Read my comments in the script to see what is happening.

https://gist.github.com/joshmoto/e23dad634fcdf6974eeca396387cba8c

```js
// jquery on ready
(function($) {

  // instagram username
  let username = 'github';

  // slide count (max ever returned in callback data for a user is 12)
  let count = 12;

  // instagram feed slider
  const $slider = $('#instagram-feed-slider');

  // grab our instagram feed
  $.instagramFeed({
    'username': username,
    'container': false,
    'display_profile': false,
    'display_biography': false,
    'display_gallery': true,
    'callback': function(data) {

      // latest owner timeline media not videos
      let media = data.edge_owner_to_timeline_media.edges;

      // slider media data
      let slides = {};

      // each media function
      $.each(media, function(i, item) {

        // current slide index
        let id = item.node.shortcode;

        // create thumb data object
        let thumb_data = {};

        // each item node thumb resource function
        $.each(item.node.thumbnail_resources, function(i, thumb) {

          // get thumb data width and src url
          thumb_data[thumb.config_width] = thumb.src;

          // add thumb data to our slides object
          slides[id] = thumb_data;

        });

      });

      // iterator counter
      let iterator = 0;

      // each slides function
      $.each(slides, function(id, slide) {

        // add 1 to iterator
        iterator++;

        // if iterator is less than or equal to count
        if (iterator <= count) {

          // create our slide html string ( div > a > img )
          let slickSlide = '<div><a href="https://www.instagram.com/p/' + id + '" target="_blank"><img src="' + slide[640] + '" alt=""/></a></div>';

          // append it to feed div
          $slider.append(slickSlide);

        }

      });

      // init slider with slick
      $slider.on('init', function(slick) {

        // do stuff here when slick initializes

        // slight delay so slick init completes render
        setTimeout(function() {

          // reveal the slider with opacity
          $slider.addClass('slick-reveal');

        // delay time .1 second
        }, 100);

      // then our slick options
      }).slick({
        mobileFirst: true,
        dots: true,
        infinite: true,
        arrows: false,
        adaptiveHeight: true,
        autoplay: true,
        slidesToShow: 2,
        slidesToScroll: 2,
        responsive: [{
            breakpoint: 480,
            settings: {
              slidesToShow: 3,
              slidesToScroll: 3
            }
          },
          {
            breakpoint: 600,
            settings: {
              slidesToShow: 4,
              slidesToScroll: 4,
            }
          },
          {
            breakpoint: 1024,
            settings: {
              slidesToShow: 6,
              slidesToScroll: 6
            }
          }
        ]
      });

    }

  });

})(jQuery);
```

```css
BODY {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px;
}

#instagram-feed-slider {
  height: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}

#instagram-feed-slider.slick-initialized {
  height: auto;
}

#instagram-feed-slider.slick-initialized.slick-reveal {
  opacity: 1;
}

#instagram-feed-slider .slick-slide {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
}

#instagram-feed-slider .slick-slide A {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#instagram-feed-slider .slick-slide IMG {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="instagram-feed-slider"></div>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.instagramFeed/1.4.1/jquery.instagramFeed.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js"></script>
```

---

Here is another version request by [@GustavoReis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8041366/gustavo-reis) to include captions in the instagram feed slick slider.

I've modified the slide object by moving `thumb_data` into slide property called `media`, and the caption into slide property called `caption`.

```
{
  B27UTWZDlZY: {
    caption: "When you’re known for speed, every step counts.",
    media: {
      150: "https://scontent-lht6-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/e35/c157.0.406.406a/s150x150/69856901_215241699458552_7535240597822423815_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-lht6-1.cdninstagram.com&amp;_nc_cat=108&amp;_nc_ohc=DWSHUK-9GosAX9mw4Ol&amp;tp=16&amp;oh=4547a183de107937cd4fc8829cb28ff6&amp;oe=5F96F63E",
      240: "https://scontent-lht6-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/e35/c157.0.406.406a/s240x240/69856901_215241699458552_7535240597822423815_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-lht6-1.cdninstagram.com&amp;_nc_cat=108&amp;_nc_ohc=DWSHUK-9GosAX9mw4Ol&amp;tp=16&amp;oh=307c0ce577bbeea2fb9ee4bbb898097a&amp;oe=5F96C138",
      320: "https://scontent-lht6-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/e35/c157.0.406.406a/s320x320/69856901_215241699458552_7535240597822423815_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-lht6-1.cdninstagram.com&amp;_nc_cat=108&amp;_nc_ohc=DWSHUK-9GosAX9mw4Ol&amp;tp=16&amp;oh=9f90ae2b01ff38419e23ee07ef3c2a02&amp;oe=5F96874E",
      480: "https://scontent-lht6-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/e35/c157.0.406.406a/69856901_215241699458552_7535240597822423815_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-lht6-1.cdninstagram.com&amp;_nc_cat=108&amp;_nc_ohc=DWSHUK-9GosAX9mw4Ol&amp;oh=33ec0085b8863af3ffda4bd1a59c809e&amp;oe=5F970099",
      640: "https://scontent-lht6-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/e35/c157.0.406.406a/69856901_215241699458552_7535240597822423815_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-lht6-1.cdninstagram.com&amp;_nc_cat=108&amp;_nc_ohc=DWSHUK-9GosAX9mw4Ol&amp;oh=33ec0085b8863af3ffda4bd1a59c809e&amp;oe=5F970099"
    }
  },
  BvzWaX8hg50: {
    caption: "For the Front team, continuous deployments are a best practice, not an exception.",
    media: {
      150: "https://scontent-lhr8-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/e35/s150x150/54511581_155220282170447_1722264597870720283_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-lhr8-1.cdninstagram.com&amp;_nc_cat=111&amp;_nc_ohc=YdpTrs4jVysAX-88LWe&amp;_nc_tp=15&amp;oh=976a0dd9be4381a97f256953d10ed769&amp;oe=5FBFD370",
      240: "https://scontent-lhr8-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/e35/s240x240/54511581_155220282170447_1722264597870720283_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-lhr8-1.cdninstagram.com&amp;_nc_cat=111&amp;_nc_ohc=YdpTrs4jVysAX-88LWe&amp;_nc_tp=15&amp;oh=2bc255b974c57f4c2ab81a7fcc726e1c&amp;oe=5FBE4926",
      320: "https://scontent-lhr8-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/e35/s320x320/54511581_155220282170447_1722264597870720283_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-lhr8-1.cdninstagram.com&amp;_nc_cat=111&amp;_nc_ohc=YdpTrs4jVysAX-88LWe&amp;_nc_tp=15&amp;oh=d3da5b238d4a70ec2f9fe7cf09ea144e&amp;oe=5FBFD2A0",
      480: "https://scontent-lhr8-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/e35/s480x480/54511581_155220282170447_1722264597870720283_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-lhr8-1.cdninstagram.com&amp;_nc_cat=111&amp;_nc_ohc=YdpTrs4jVysAX-88LWe&amp;_nc_tp=15&amp;oh=250ecd60fa86c6aeabd2a236036d1f7b&amp;oe=5FBC2546",
      640: "https://scontent-lhr8-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/sh0.08/e35/s640x640/54511581_155220282170447_1722264597870720283_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-lhr8-1.cdninstagram.com&amp;_nc_cat=111&amp;_nc_ohc=YdpTrs4jVysAX-88LWe&amp;_nc_tp=24&amp;oh=84e330986ce3ae71ed1895c5a2a9690b&amp;oe=5FBDF4C9"
    }
  },
  ByahrrSDqVa: {
    caption: "Going from silos to a shared environment is a challenge.",
    media: {
      150: "https://scontent-lhr8-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/e35/s150x150/63430826_120138045872791_614866485576038131_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-lhr8-1.cdninstagram.com&amp;_nc_cat=107&amp;_nc_ohc=lIqX8s7NhLQAX-LlxUs&amp;_nc_tp=15&amp;oh=123a990bf0f44e97caacc68994832055&amp;oe=5FBE7B20",
      240: "https://scontent-lhr8-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/e35/s240x240/63430826_120138045872791_614866485576038131_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-lhr8-1.cdninstagram.com&amp;_nc_cat=107&amp;_nc_ohc=lIqX8s7NhLQAX-LlxUs&amp;_nc_tp=15&amp;oh=712e92714159df1a7deedb3e8f9fdc23&amp;oe=5FBD1AAB",
      320: "https://scontent-lhr8-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/e35/s320x320/63430826_120138045872791_614866485576038131_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-lhr8-1.cdninstagram.com&amp;_nc_cat=107&amp;_nc_ohc=lIqX8s7NhLQAX-LlxUs&amp;_nc_tp=15&amp;oh=ce04f8a32e2fe225e66b7cb4f99c5987&amp;oe=5FBC3C13",
      480: "https://scontent-lhr8-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/e35/s480x480/63430826_120138045872791_614866485576038131_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-lhr8-1.cdninstagram.com&amp;_nc_cat=107&amp;_nc_ohc=lIqX8s7NhLQAX-LlxUs&amp;_nc_tp=15&amp;oh=5a4c624b33388220fc0623204f0d006d&amp;oe=5FBF8D4F",
      640: "https://scontent-lhr8-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/sh0.08/e35/s640x640/63430826_120138045872791_614866485576038131_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-lhr8-1.cdninstagram.com&amp;_nc_cat=107&amp;_nc_ohc=lIqX8s7NhLQAX-LlxUs&amp;_nc_tp=24&amp;oh=c9ba3bee3d16a32ceeaee5f951cdc592&amp;oe=5FBC907F"
    }
  },
  ...
}
```

See comments in code below, if anyone can improve concept please post an answer with updated code or alternative solution.

```js
// jquery on ready
(function($) {

  // instagram username
  let username = 'github';

  // slide count (max ever returned in callback data for a user is 12)
  let count = 12;

  // instagram feed slider
  const $slider = $('#instagram-feed-slider');

  // grab our instagram feed
  $.instagramFeed({
    'username': username,
    'container': false,
    'display_profile': false,
    'display_biography': false,
    'display_gallery': true,
    'callback': function(data) {

      // view raw instagram callback data
      // console.log(data);

      // latest owner timeline media not videos
      let media = data.edge_owner_to_timeline_media.edges;

      // slider media data
      let slides = {};

      // each media function
      $.each(media, function(i, item) {

        // current slide index
        let id = item.node.shortcode;
        
        // set slides id as object
        slides[id] = {};
        
        // get media caption from item
        let caption = item.node.edge_media_to_caption.edges;
        
        // check media caption is an array
        if($.isArray(caption)) {
        
           // check if we have caption array item 
           if(caption[0]) {
            
            // set caption as caption
            slides[id].caption = caption[0].node.text;
            
          }
        
        }
        
        // create thumb data object
        let thumb_data = {};

        // each item node thumb resource function
        $.each(item.node.thumbnail_resources, function(i, thumb) {

          // get thumb data width and src url
          thumb_data[thumb.config_width] = thumb.src;

          // add thumb data to our slides object
          slides[id].media = thumb_data;

        });

      });
      
      // use this console the our custom slick instagram slides data
      //console.log(slides);

      // iterator counter
      let iterator = 0;

      // each slides function
      $.each(slides, function(id, slide) {

        // add 1 to iterator
        iterator++;

        // if iterator is less than or equal to count
        if (iterator <= count) {

          // create our slide html string ( div > a > img )
          let slickSlide = '';
          
          // build our slick slide figure image with figcaption
          slickSlide += '<figure>';
          slickSlide += '<a href="https://www.instagram.com/p/' + id + '" target="_blank">';
          slickSlide += '<img src="' + slide.media[640] + '" alt=""/>';
          slickSlide += '</a>';
          
          // if we have a caption
          if(slide.caption) {
          
            // add figcaption to figure
            slickSlide += '<figcaption>' + slide.caption + '</figcaption>';
            
          }
          
          // close our slick slide figure
          slickSlide += '</figure>';

          // append figure slide to instagram feed slider div
          $slider.append(slickSlide);

        }

      });

      // init slider with slick
      $slider.on('init', function(slick) {

        // do stuff here when slick initializes

        // slight delay so slick init completes render
        setTimeout(function() {

          // reveal the slider with opacity
          $slider.addClass('slick-reveal');

          // delay time .1 second
        }, 100);

        // then our slick options
      }).slick({
        mobileFirst: true,
        dots: true,
        infinite: true,
        arrows: false,
        adaptiveHeight: true,
        autoplay: true,
        slidesToShow: 2,
        slidesToScroll: 2,
        responsive: [{
            breakpoint: 480,
            settings: {
              slidesToShow: 3,
              slidesToScroll: 3
            }
          },
          {
            breakpoint: 600,
            settings: {
              slidesToShow: 4,
              slidesToScroll: 4,
            }
          },
          {
            breakpoint: 1024,
            settings: {
              slidesToShow: 6,
              slidesToScroll: 6
            }
          }
        ]
      });

    }

  });

})(jQuery);
```

```css
BODY {
  font-family: 'Helvetica', serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px;
}

#instagram-feed-slider {
  height: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}

#instagram-feed-slider.slick-initialized {
  height: auto;
}

#instagram-feed-slider.slick-initialized.slick-reveal {
  opacity: 1;
}

#instagram-feed-slider .slick-slide {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#instagram-feed-slider .slick-slide A {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#instagram-feed-slider .slick-slide IMG {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

#instagram-feed-slider .slick-slide FIGCAPTION {
  font-size: 80%;
  hyphens: auto;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div id="instagram-feed-slider"></div>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.instagramFeed/1.4.1/jquery.instagramFeed.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js"></script>
```

Here is a fiddle version https://jsfiddle.net/joshmoto/xepLr83h/1/

Comment: Please check our chat, @joshmoto.